# Advice on how to program this one line

Tags: c

Am studying some basic C program and I have this one line that I cant figure out. The program should ask the user to enter the amount of data (s)he used for the bill cycle in GB through cmd prompt.

Output should look like this:

```
Enter the number of GB used: __GB    //user inputs the data consumed in the " __"
```

The best I came up with is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    float GB_used;
    printf("\nEnter the number of GB used: GB");
    scanf("%f", &GB_used);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Enter the number of GB used: GB__      //where " __" is where user inputs
```

Please help. The user need to only enters float/int. Is this a problem with the instructions?

Comment: Maybe start with learning [how **printf** works](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), particularly how to format data provided as parameters.

Comment: You should use probably read in a string, then convert with strtol to check for errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *backspaces* to move back after outputting the last `GB`. Something like

```
printf("\nEnter the number of GB used:         GB\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
```

But I think you should not want to do that. Either use a full screen library (gtk) or if you use line mode avoid going back.

Comment: That worked! thanks so much for replying. I wasn't introduced to "/b" syntax in class yet, but we learn everyday

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to validate what's entered.

Take a look at [How to input a number from user in C](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284385&answer=1043372399)